# Wordpress get max post meta between values

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress, post-meta

I already have a query like :

```
SELECT max(cast(meta_value as unsigned)) AS max_racer_nr FROM wp_postmeta WHERE meta_key='racer_nr'
```

I need to get max `racer_nr` which is between **1** - **99** or **100** - **199**, or **200** - **999** depending on which class racer belongs to.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT MAX(CAST(`meta_value` AS unsigned)) AS `max_racer_nr` FROM `wp_postmeta` WHERE `meta_key` = 'racer_nr' AND `meta_value` BETWEEN 1 AND 99;
```

or

```
SELECT MAX(CAST(`meta_value` AS unsigned)) AS `max_racer_nr` FROM `wp_postmeta` WHERE `meta_key` = 'racer_nr' AND `meta_value` >= 1 AND `meta_value` <= 99;
```

You'd just have to change the values in your PHP code depending on the class of the racer. Unless I misunderstand what you need.

Comment: That's it !!! :)  i thought that I need to check each meta_key with values.. not just meta_value.. soo simple it was.. :))) thank you!!! :))